# Distance between uset input numbers in a 2d array java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I'm a beginner programmer and need some help with 2dimensional arrays. 
My program has to read how many rows and columns there will be in the array(it's a square so, the numbers are the same and are set by "d" in the program below), and also has to read the number "n" which basically tells the program how many inputs there will be in the array. Then, the user adds "n" numbers from the array and the output needs to be the distance between all the input numbers (the distance between the first and second, second and third,...). I have to move by a manhattan distance.

```
int d=sc.nextInt();
int n=sc.nextInt();

int[][] array=new int[d][d]; //length and heigth of array

int distance=0;
int c=0;
for(int i=0;i>d;i++){
    for(int j=0;j>d;j++){
        array[i][j]=c;
        c++;

        distance=Math.abs(i)+Math.abs(j);
    }

}
System.out.println(distance);
```

This is what I have so far. I just really need some help with filling my code with the part that actually sums all the distances together and then prints it.
Ty

Comment: you dont even need n. you never use it again. do you already have the code for reading the user input for the array?

Comment: it's an assignment so, user has to input n as how many inputs there will be. no, I don't know how to do it. I've tried the same as goes for a 1d array but it didn't work.

Comment: any ideas on how I'd make kind of a for loop for reading the "n" inputs?